# Char sort plus print with rows and columns

Tags: c++

Hello i really need help, should make from two chars to camper first with second and if some symbol is include, should print them in row and column, also in same position where they are same; if my inputs are gold and xxlz should look like this.

```
     x
     x 
   gold
     z
```

if they they dont had same symbol should print on last index of first word.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char firstWord[15];
    char secondWord[15];
    cout << "enter first than second word\n";
    cin >> firstWord >> secondWord;
    int lenthOne = strlen(firstWord);
    int lenthSecond = strlen(secondWord);
    for (int i = 0; i < lenthOne; i++) {
        cout << firstWord[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < lenthSecond; j++) {
            if (firstWord[i] == secondWord[j]) {
                cout << secondWord;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to start using `std::string` instead of raw c-style character arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved already the comparison of each character of both words.

Now, after having found a match, you need to show the crossword. For that, we imagine a 2-dimensional grid of rows and columns. Like the below

```
    column
row 01234 
  0   x 
  1   x 
  2 gold
  3   l
  4
```

We need to print row by row. If the row is equal to the matching index of the first word ("gold", character 'l', index 3), then we need to print the complete first word.

If not, then we first need sto print a number of blanks. Also here the number is given by index of the matched character, but here of the second word.

So, we will print the number of blanks as explained above and then output the character of the second word at the index of the row.

Very simple.

There are many many potential solutions. I will show one of the many, but I will not use C-Style char arrays for strings. In C++ we use `std::string` for that. But you may simply adapt that also to C-style.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    // Here we will store the owrds that shall be evaluated
    std::string firstWord{}, secondWord{};

    // Tell user, what to do and get the words
    std::cout << "Enter first and second word\n";
    std::cin >> firstWord >> secondWord;
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // Here we will remember, if there was a match at all
    bool matchFound{};

    // Now compare all characters of first word with all characters of second word
    for (size_t firstWordIndex{}; firstWordIndex < firstWord.length(); ++firstWordIndex) {
        for (size_t secondWordIndex{}; secondWordIndex < secondWord.length(); ++secondWordIndex) {

            // Check, if we have an equal character in both words
            if (firstWord[firstWordIndex] == secondWord[secondWordIndex]) {

                // Remember that we found at least one match
                matchFound = true;

                // We found a matching character. Now show the crossword
                for (size_t row{}; row < firstWord.length(); ++row) {

                    // If we shall show the complete second word
                    if (row == firstWordIndex) {
                        std::cout << firstWord << '\n';
                    }
                    else {
                        // Show only part of second word. Insert blanks before
                        for (size_t blankCounter{}; blankCounter < secondWordIndex; ++blankCounter)
                            std::cout << ' ';
                        // print letter
                        std::cout << secondWord[row] << '\n';
                    }
                }
                std::cout << "\n\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
    // If there was no match, then simply show both words
    if (not matchFound) {
        std::cout << firstWord << '\n';
        // Use a separate row for each character of the second word
        for (size_t row{}; row < secondWord.length(); ++row) {

            // print blanks in front of character
            for (size_t blankCounter{}; blankCounter < firstWord.length(); ++blankCounter)
                std::cout << ' ';

            // Print the character
            std::cout << secondWord[row] << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```